# how to set up python web dev environment

Tags: python, apache

the set the i have so far is:
windows 7 64bit
Apache 2.2.14/mysql/php 5.3.1

i installed python 2.7. not configured.

i tried installing mod_python but it kept telling python 2.5 is required

Comment: I'd highly recommend using mod_wsgi instead of mod_python. The latter is deprecated and probably will be unmaintained before long; WSGI is the standard way to run a Python script in a web server.

Comment: WSGI, and a linux box too. The closer you are to the production environment, the less surprises you will have when deploying.

Comment: @Luper: His production environment might not be Linux. WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, Perl/Python/PHP/etc.) isn't as common as LAMP, but it's far from unheard of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump mod_python. [It's dead, Jim](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html).